# Mongoose Model static/method not holding the value in "this"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js

I was trying to implementing the passport js authentication with the mongodb user model. Now as you can see, i have created a method on the user model. And therefore when I apply this method on an instance of the user, i expect "this" to hold all the user object. But that is not happening in this case. Following is a working code, but i have passed an additional variable to make it work. But i did not want to do it that way. Where am i making the mistake?

And below is the passport config file for signin

```
var passport = require('passport');
var User = require('../models/users');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser((user, done)=>{
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done)=>{
  User.findById(id, (err, user)=>{
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use('local.signin', new LocalStrategy({
usernameField: 'email', passwordField: 'password', passReqToCallback: true
},(req, email, password, done) => {
User.findOne({email:email}, (err, user) => {
    if (err){ return done(err)}
    if (!user){return done(null, false, {message:'This email is not registered'})}
      if (!user.validatePassword(password, user.password)){
/**********************************************/
//is this field user.password really necessary?
/**********************************************/
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Authentication Failed'})
      } else {
          return done(null, user);
      }
  });
}));
```

The user model is as given below:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var userSchema = new Schema({
  salutation: {type: String, required: false},
  firstname: {type: String, required: true},
  lastname: {type: String, required: false},
  email: {type: String, required: true},
  password: {type: String, required: true}
});

userSchema.methods.validatePassword = (password, x) => {
  console.log(this); //this is returning null
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, x);
/*********************************************************/
//I was excepting this.password to work instead of using x
/*********************************************************/
}

userSchema.methods.myCourses = (userId) => {
  console.log(this.enrolledFor);
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Comment: try `function (password, x) {` instead of `(password, x) =>`

Comment: Hi @GrégoryNEUT, appreciate your help. The thing is working just fine. But my problem is that the line above this `console.log(this)` is returning a null. But that should have returned a user object. At least that is what i was expecting it to do :-(

Comment: The things is when you use arrow functions (ES syntax), the context inside the function is the inherited one. Idk if even with regular context you can access the user from here, but you can try.

Comment: Oh... it worked. I did not know the nuanced difference between the => and the function... Will be required to read about them. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: it's k I put it as answer tho to close your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECMA2015 standard also called ES6 allow the use of arrow functions, theses functions inherits theirs context from the upper context.

The soluce is to use regular function syntax.

```
userSchema.methods.validatePassword = function (password, x) {
  console.log(this); //this is returning null
  return bcrypt.compareSync(password, x);
/*********************************************************/
//I was excepting this.password to work instead of using x
/*********************************************************/
}
----------
```

[Article about arrow functions](https://www.sitepoint.com/es6-arrow-functions-new-fat-concise-syntax-javascript/)

> Arrow functions – also called “fat arrow” functions, from CoffeeScript
>   (a transcompiled language) are a more concise syntax for writing
>   function expressions. They utilize a new token, =>, that looks like a
>   fat arrow. Arrow functions are anonymous and change the way this binds
>   in functions.
>
> Arrow functions make our code more concise, and simplify function
>   scoping and the this keyword. They are one-line mini functions which
>   work much like Lambdas in other languages like C# or Python. (See also
>   lambdas in JavaScript). By using arrow function we avoid having to
>   type the function keyword, return keyword (it’s implicit in arrow
>   functions), and curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax compared to function expressions and does not bind its own this, arguments, super, or new.target. Arrow functions are always anonymous. These function expressions are best suited for non-method functions and they can not be used as constructors.
>   [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 0):

Don’t use arrow functions when you use Mongoose Schema.methods or Schema.statics because arrow functions don’t bind the this keyword as the function expression does. So basically, when you try to use arrow functions as an argument of Schema.method(), you’ll get undefined each time you reference a definition value from your Schema.